# Find an uncountable number of subsets of $l_n^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $l_n^p(\mathbb{C})$ which is neither open nor closed .

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Find an uncountable number of subsets of $l_n^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $l_n^p(\mathbb{C})$ which is neither open nor closed .

I think if we define for positive $a\in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ the subset $A_a=[0,a)\times\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ .Number of $A_a$ is uncountable .

Each $A_a$ is neither open or closed

Reason : For each $a$ we have $\mathbb{R^n}-A_a=\{(- \infty,a)\cup[a,\infty)\}\times\mathbb{R^{n-1}}$ which is neither open nor closed .

So the collection of subsets  $A_a$ of $\mathbb{R^n}$ satisfies the requirements .

In a similar way if defines for each $a\in \mathbb{R}$ the subset $B_a=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$ satisfies the requirement of being in uncountable in number and neither closed nor open .

I would just like to know if my proof is alright . If you any other subsets satisfying the requirements please provide . Thank you .

Comment: What exactly is $l_n^p(\mathbb{R})$? The index $n$ irritates me, as it would imply that only finite sequences are involved (which also is part of your answer). I'm only (vaguely) familiar with inifinite sequences, where it makes sense to think about convergence of an infinite sum of sequence members taken to the power $p$.

Comment: I too have never heard of $l^p_n(\mathbb{R})$ or $l^p_n(\mathbb{C})$. From how you write it sounds like it is just $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ with the $p$-norm, but the norm is completely irrelevant in this context (you could just as well say "with its usual topology"). Also, the $B_a$ in your $\mathbb{C}$ case does not depend on $a$.

Comment: The text i'm using denotes ${l_n}^p(\mathbb{R}) $ denotes the space $(\mathbb{R^n} , d_p )$ where $d_p(x,y)= ( \sum_{1}^{n} |x_j-y_j|^p )^{1/p}  , x,y \in \mathbb{R^n} $

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said. In this context the only thing that matters is the topology, so you can just say "in the usual topology". In that case your first proof is fine, but your second one makes no sense (again because $B_a$ does not depend on $a$).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification. Your answer works for $l_n^p(\mathbb{R})$, but not for $l_n^p(\mathbb{C})$, because $B_a$ is closed. But even your construction and arguments for $l_n^p(\mathbb{R})$ are a bit sloppy.

For example, why do you choose $a \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$? If we are dealing with real numbers, the irrationals are nothing special and nowhere in your argument is it used or needed that $a$ is irrational. To me it looks like you remember some argument about intervals being open/closed when dealing with $\mathbb{Q}$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}$, but that has no relevance here.

Then you continue with discussing why $A_a$ is not open/closed. $A_a$ is defined as a cross product between a finite interval and several copies of $\mathbb{R}$. Your argument goes that the complement of $A_a$, which is a slighter more complicated cross product, is not open/closed. But any argument you could do to actually prove that would most probably be applicable to $A_a$ itself.

For $A_a$, you correctly found a neither open nor closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ and could extend this to correctly create a neither open nor closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you can similarly construct a neither open nor closed set in $\mathbb{C}$, you can also extend  this to $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

For $r\in \mathbb R$ and $m\in \mathbb N$ , let $v(r,m)$ be the vector whose  $j$-th co-ordinates are all $0$ for $j>1$ and whose first co-ordinate is $r-2^{-m}$. Then $S(r)=\{v(r,m):m\in \mathbb N\}$ is not open and not closed.

For $0<s$ let $T(s)=[0,s)\times \{0\}^{n-1}$ if the dimension $n$ is greater than $1$, or $T(s)=[0,s)$ if $n=1$. Then $T(s)$ is not open and not closed.

Let $\bar 0$ denote the $0$-vector. When $v$ is a vector with $d_p(v,\bar 0)\geq 1$ then $U(v)=\{v\}\cup B_p(\bar 0,1)=\{v\}\cup \{u: d_p(u,\bar 0)<1\}$ is not open and not closed.